# Is there a way to format now()'s timestamp to year-month-day like 2018-11-11?

Tags: formatting

as title says ;-)
I want to get now()'s timestamp to year month day, e.g.

```
uint64_t formated_date(uint64_t tm) {
    // 1542014702 -> 20181112172502
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it can be done in contract for that you need to add some functionality into contract that will generate date from timestamp but if it can be done in front end side only then it will be cost effective for users.

Comment: thanks, I've implement it in my contract just follow gmtime.c ;-)